# How do I sequentially increment number within a text string?

Tags: vba, ms-word, notepad++, ms-office, increment

Here is a scenario,

```
id:"564"
id:"367"
id:"901"
```

are scattered around a huge word document, I would need a solution to find the areas where these alphanemeric words are and change them to something like this

```
id:"200"
id:"201"
id:"202"
```

Comment: I added the word-vba tag for you, I was going to add VBA on its own as well, but you are capped at 5 tags.  If you think VBA as a stand alone tag would be better than the other feel free to add it.

Comment: You could set up a linked field between Excel and Word but that seems like a lot for a *sequence* of numbers. I would recommend using a SEQ or  even a LISTNUM field in word.

Comment: Please how do I do this place can you be detailed?. Thanks

Comment: Peter, I recommend you learn how to use Word's built-in FIND functionality to locate the `id: ###` in the document, using the wildcards option. Once you have that working, record it in a macro. Use the [edit] link below the question to add that code. Based on it, we can show you how to remove the current number and replace it with an incrementing field (or a static number if you prefer that). If you read in the [help] on asking questions on Stack Overflow you'll notice that this is not a free coding service or a tutorial site. You're expected to do a certain amount of research and work...

Answer (score 1):

You can do that within column mode edition.

- Press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.
- Select the columns to change with the mouse.
- Choose menu `Edition` > `Column mode edition` (I don't know the exact name, I haven't an english version of Npp)
- Check number to insert.
- Initial number : `200`
- Increment: `1`
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>